# DX Package:Install throwing errors via Command Line

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx-cli

I've been walking through the ISV DX session [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTTbymAAtAg) with a test package in preparation for migrating my general package development to DX

It went pretty well until the final step - installing the new beta package in a test scratch org. I created a new DX scratch org with a new alias, but I can't install the package into that org via the CLI or UI

Create a new Org:

```
$ sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/KW_TEST_SCRATCH2-scratch-def.json --setalias testorg3
```

Then tried to install package into that new org:

```
$ sfdx force:package:install --targetusername testorg3 --id 04tXXX
--wait 10
```

> ERROR:  Encountered errors installing the package! ERROR: 
>   Installation errors:
>   1) Package(033XXX) The package already exists.,
>   Details: You can't install a package into the org where it was
>   created.

But that alias has a different Org Id according to the Org List, and when I log in, the package definitely isn't there.

Feel like I am just missing something obvious, but I've tried numerous things and so far, no joy...

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. I am using Illuminated Cloud, but was creating QA Orgs via the Command Line to test out the CLI. The folder I was using was for the scratch org project to build my test package - so the sfdx-project file had a namespace set since this is a managed package.

But I wasn't appreciating the difference between the sfdx-project.json file and the project-scratch def file. So I think the scratch orgs for qa were being created with that namespace because they were all using same sfdx-project file even though I had created different definition files.

What I found was that once I created a new project that wasn't referencing a namespace and created my orgs from that directory, I was able to create a new scratch org and install my package without issue. Having worked that out, I discovered the "--nonamespace" parameter which is just for this purpose - create a project but explicitly don't set the namespace